# Check what Program creates a file

Tags: python-3.8

Is there any way to see what program creates or deletes a file in Python? I know that you can write a program that prints out when a File was created/deleted/modified using watchdog but I want to know what program creates/deletes/modifies this file. Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great question and *can* done using the [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module. The os module is used for many things, one of those being [directory management](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/directory) and is perfect for what you are asking. The code in the following examples is mine and is referenced from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) as mentioned previously.

## Creating a file

One must take precautions when creating a file to ensure you do not corrupt or delete already existing files. Please read the following code carefully.

```py
""" 
First open the file with os.open(). This is used when ever you want to create or modify a
file and is the bread and butter of the following operations. 
"""
with open("Desired_file.txt", 'w') as file:
    # Actions
    file.close()
```

Now at this point you may be asking: what is 'w'? This is the flag that we are opening the file with. w is the flag that is used in two primary scenarios:
 1. When you want to **create** a file that does not already exist.
2. When you want to **overwrite** a file.

You may also be asking, ***What is file.close()?*** the close function is essentially like hitting ctrl+s on your keyboard. **It is saving the file to make sure that any changes that we have saved are recorded.**

## Adding text to a file

Like in the first example, adding text to a file is a simple matter of changing the flag variable from `w` to `a`. An example of this can be found below.

```py
with open("file.txt", "a") as file:
    file.append("Note: Add fish to shopping list.")
    file.close()
```

Note that `file.close` is used because we want to **save our changes**.

## Reading a file

This is again, simply a matter of changing the flag to `"a"`. See practical usage in the following example.

```py
with open("Desired_file.txt", "r") as file:
    # Get the file data with file.read()
    file_data = file.read()
    file.close()
```

It is important to note that this is not a good way to read files because if you have lines in your file it will print `'\n'` as a variable because it prints information in list format. To avoid this I like to use the .split() function after the .read() function. Another practical-usage example can be seen below.

```py
with open("Desired_file.txt", "r") as file:
    file_data = file.read().split()

    file.close()
```

Now the final step is to read each line in the file. See below.

```py
with open("Desired_file.txt", "r") as file:
    file_data = file.read().split()

    for line in file_data:
        print(line)

    # Note that at this point the file has finished reading the file. Now all that we have to do is save the file 
    file.close()
```

I really hoped this helped. If you have any questions I would be more than happy to assist. I apologise that I don't have the best way of explaining things and this could be way more simplified but I hope it's readable enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.remove(fiile)
```

This is how you remove  a file. Hope it helps